# Why doesn't optimization result in the same weights for all neurons in the same layer?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I would like to understand why in a single-layer network, given that all neurons use the same training examples (all of them), the gradient descent method does not reach the same solution for the weights of each neuron. In other words, if the equations are identical for the activation function of each neuron, why does the solution converge to different weights for each neuron?

Comment: What do you mean by single-layer network?

Comment: I guess initial weights are randomised in some way. Otherwise the same input to the same system will produce the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous answers/comments have pointed out that this is precisely the reason why random initialization is done in practice. To elaborate a bit further:

---

Suppose we have $n$ samples with inputs $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, and a single hidden layer with $d$ neurons, with outputs $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$.

Then the neural network $f$ will be performing the mapping:
$$ f(\mathbf{X}) = \sigma(\sigma(\mathbf{XW + b})\mathbf{W}_2 + \mathbf{b}_2) $$
where $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$, $\mathbf{W}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times 1}$ are the weights and $\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{b}_2$ the biases, $\sigma(.)$ the activation functions.

For simplicity, let's suppose we have identity activation functions $\sigma(t) = t$, no bias terms $\mathbf{b} \equiv 0 \equiv \mathbf{b}_2$, and we are training via mean-squared-error loss.

In the backpropagation step, the gradients of the loss function for a single example w.r.t. $\mathbf{W}_2$ are
$$ \nabla_{\mathbf{W}_2} \ (y_i - x_i'\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}_2)^2 \propto 2x_i'\mathbf{W}(x_i'\mathbf{WW}_2 - y_i) $$
and analogously for $\mathbf{W}$ by the chain rule. We can see that if $\mathbf{W}, \mathbf{W}_2$ are initialized to exactly identical values (not necessarily 0), the gradients w.r.t. each neuron in the weights are the same. We then end up in the same weights for each neuron.

However if the weights were randomly initialized to different values, both the initial values and each gradient step are different across neurons. We then end up with different weights for each neuron.

---

Here is some simple code to play around with to build some intuition.

```
import numpy as np

# Simulate some data
N = 100
K = 2
X = np.random.normal(size=(N, K))
Y = 1*X[:,[0]] + 2*X[:,[1]]

def optimize_mse(X, Y, W_hidden_init, W_out, lr=0.1, epochs=5):
    N = X.shape[0]
    W_t = W_hidden_init
    for t in range(epochs):
        print(W_t)
        grad = -(1/N) * X.T @ (Y - X @ W_t)
        W_t = W_t - lr*grad
    return W_t

d = 3  # Number of neurons
W_out = np.random.normal(size=(d, 1))
```

Identical initializations of hidden layer:

```
W_hidden_init = np.zeros(shape=(K, d))
optimize_mse(X, Y, W_hidden_init, W_out, lr=0.1, epochs=5)
## >> array([[0.40432928, 0.40432928, 0.40432928],
       [0.89144276, 0.89144276, 0.89144276]])
```

Random initializations of hidden layer:

```
W_hidden_init = np.random.normal(size=(K, d))
optimize_mse(X, Y, W_hidden_init, W_out, lr=0.1, epochs=5)
## >> array([[0.68902164, 0.67819881, 0.67577952],
       [0.54966617, 1.06033003, 0.15538775]])
```

Comment: Many thanks, Adam. Now I understand the math behind it. However, when we initialize the weights at random values, I was wondering why the optimization reaches different values (I can see that for each neuron the change rate will be different based on the initial random weigth). Do we have local minima for each one of the solutions?

Comment: @JohannaMN I've added some simple code in the post that may be helpful to play around with. We would obtain local minima of the joint loss function via standard SGD, which would generally have different values for each neuron. Of course it is entirely possible that they are the same - the point here is that with identical initializations, we are constraining all the neurons in the hidden layer to be **always** the same (no matter how long we train). This limits the set of functions the neural network can learn.

Comment: Many thanks Adam, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you started with all weights set to zero, say, then yes, they should all update exactly the same way and all the weights on a given layer would be the same. In that case, the expressive power of the neural network would be very limited. To break this symmetry, the weights of the network are always initialized randomly before training begins.